# Does killProcess(Process.myPid()) calls onDestroy()?

Tags: java, android

Does `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())` calls **onDestroy() / super.onDestroy()** method? (in any case)

Comment: What do you observe when you run `killProcess(Process.myPid())` ?

Comment: Where does the `killProcess(Process)` method come from?

Comment: ben75, nothing On SCREEN. and voidHead, this is "android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());"